# Why do processes start appearing at the top of the tree's root instead of where they should, underneath wininit.exe and explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-10, process, process-explorer

Why do these processes appear at the top of the Process Explorer window instead of below the `wininit.exe` section where they should be?

**Some Facts**

- Starts happening after about 10-30 minutes of system uptime.
- Happens on (1) fresh install and (2) fully updated install of Win 10 LTSC 2021 21H2
- Happens on *all* versions of [Process Explorer (current is v17.02)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- Happens on [ProcessHacker v2.39](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/downloads.php)
- Does **NOT** happen on [System Informer (nightly 2023-02-19)](https://systeminformer.sourceforge.io/nightly.php)
- It's difficult to troubleshoot because it seems to take about 30 minutes for the OS to warm up before it happens

The commands suggested by John are working so far, after nearly an hour. I'm still testing them.

```
$ Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
$ Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
$ sfc.exe /SCANNOW
```

[image: Process Explorer]

Comment: No issue here (Windows 11 and 10).  Try clicking on the Process Column to sort it.

Comment: Thanks, sorting by Process Column removes the tree entirely. Note: use `View > Show Process Tree` to revert.

Comment: *Why* should all of those processes be under wininit.exe? Some of them indeed seem out of place (svchost should only ever be under services.exe), but in general it's normal for some processes to end up "outside". Have you tried other similar tools such as ProcessHacker (aka System Informer, these days), to see whether they agree with ProcExp?

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Click several times (I clicked 3 times) and it went back to the default setting and then it worked properly

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC to see if that corrects your issue.   ...  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Install the latest version of  [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), currently v17.02. Mine doesn't do that. Note that to correctly see System processes, Process Explorer must be run as Administrator.

Comment: I updated the question above. Key points: System Informer does *not* have this problem. John's `DISM.exe` commands seem to be working so far. It's difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Why? Truly simple: Their parent process is gone, so now they have no parent. Windows doesn’t care either way.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you and I trust you will acknowledge

Comment: @DanielB If the parent process is gone, why does System Informer think the parent process is still present? Also, the parent process for some of those should definitely be `explorer.exe`. I don't think it has "gone away."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows recycles process identifiers (PIDs)... Every process has a parent identifier (PID) and it remains static and never changes. You will always have the same parent PID even after the parent terminates and the PID re-assigned to different processes.

It's not possible to display the parent/child family tree relationship because identifiers are recycled, so applications will also validate the creation time of the parent against the creation time of the child - The creation time also doesn't change (remains static) for the lifetime of the process even when the system clock or timezone changes.

If the creation time is newer; the real parent was terminated and the parent PID was recycled (i.e. cannot be the real parent) while older creation time is absolutely the correct parent? Children cannot be created before their parents... the problem is when the system clock or timezone change, existing processes return time values based on the previous clock (2050 time) while new processes return time values based on the new clock (1995 time).

Start the machine at 3PM and change the clock or timezone so the time is now 2PM and every new process has a creation time (2PM) before other processes (3PM) and are displayed above the System process because they have creation times (2PM) before the System process (3PM). Also since new processes are created with PIDs recycled from terminated processes the change in time causes children processes to be displayed as their parents (Grandfather paradox) or displayed in the wrong locations with incorrect parents or children and nothing can be done to fix the issue.

For example (using your screenshot to demonstrate):

[image: example]

Some processes in your screenshot (e.g. Registry) are shown as parents but they're supposed to children and some other processes are incorrectly displayed as children of svchost.exe when they're supposed to be parents.

The only way you can fix the parenting is rebooting the machine so all processes have the correct timezone for creation time... If you're using a VM then make sure you've configured the system clock and timezone inside the VM because synchronization software only temporarily changes the clock during logon and resets when shutting down the VM.

> Starts happening after about 10-30 minutes of system uptime.

Physical hardware or virtual machine? Do you have Hyper-V, Core isolation, VBS, hypervisor enabled on the physical machine? These override the physical clock oscillator chip frequency and Microsoft's hypervisor always returns a fixed value that might be messing with software or causing clock drift.

The chips included with PCs are cheap components and have daily clock drift anywhere from 6 seconds to 1 hour each day. The NTP service would be running after 10-30 minutes and updating the clock with a wrong value... Check the Event Log > System for NTP events with any suspiciously large deltas:

[image: NTP Event]

> Does NOT happen on System Informer

System Informer recently added experimental support for a very new (and very undocumented) feature introduced with recent Windows 10 and Windows 11 kernels named process sequence numbers and they're monotonically non decreasing sequences with ordering guarantees not influenced by PID recycling, clock/timezone changes or any other interference.

The monotonic sequence identifiers have certain mathematical guarantees and are significantly more reliable for child/parent validation and 100% accurate display of parent/child process trees than was what possible with PIDs on previous versions of Windows... They're already used by Windows Task Manager and System Informer (nightly builds only) and Process Explorer won't be too far away.

If something doesn't make sense feel free to ask for more info :)

Comment: Going to mark this as correct and test later. Would you mind posting a TLDR? e.g. *Those processes are not under their parent because the system clock was probably changed* The machine where this happens is a VM.

Comment: @Jeff Post the TLDR in a comment or as a separate answer?

Comment: Edit your existing answer and post the TLDR at the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked 3 machines and 1 virtual machine and all machines produce the same results for V17.03.  You may have to click the process column two or three times to cycle back to the same display.

If your system is not working correctly, then DISM / SFC may fix this issue.

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

Comment: Clicking the Process column 3 times after processes begin appearing in the root of Process Explorer does not work.

Comment: If you click on the colum, then click again and then maybe click again, does it NOT cycle?

Comment: Yes, it cycles through the views properly. I arrive back to the view that shows the tree (View > Show Process Tree), but the processes are still outside the tree. I'm working on your Dism.exe and sfc.exe commands now, but boy it sure takes a long time to test this. The important fact here is that, *System Informer shows the processes correctly when Process Explorer does NOT.*

Comment: DISM and SFC are initial repairs and a good starting point if you have multiple machines. The more aggressive repair is a Repair Install

Comment: Thanks. These are throwaway VM test installs. I'm trying to get to the bottom of what's going on.